# How Do I access iis by private ip addreress using azure.microsoft.com?

Tags: iis

I have created a vm using azure.microsoft.com

I have installed IIS it is working in localhost,

how do I remotly access the iis by public or private ip address ?

Comment: If you can access `http://localhost` on this VM already, then open up port 80 on both Windows Firewall as well as Azure Portal for this VM. Only then `http://<public IP>` starts to work.

Comment: @LexLi done great work

Comment: @LexLi I bought a domain name from OnlyDomains now how can I point it to my website

Comment: For that you should post new questions and see if anyone would like to help.